# How to write a python computer program that will take any valid arithmetic expression as a string and will output a list(or array of string)?

Tags: python, arrays, string, arithmetic-expressions

How to write a python computer program that will take any valid arithmetic expression as a string and will output a list (or array of string) of individual objects of the expression such as numbers, operators, variables, and parenthesis?

***Example#1:***

**Input:**

```
x + 2
```

**Output:**

```
["x", "+", "2"]
```

***Example#2:***

**Input:**

```
2 * count + 17
```

**Output:**

```
["2", "*", "count", "+", "17"]
```

***Example#3:***

**Input:**

```
(12+x1)*(y2-15)
```

**Output:**

```
["(", "12", "+", "x1", ")", "*", "(", "y2", "-", "15", ")"]
```

Comment: Your examples and output just seem to be removing (replacing) whitespace and then turning a string into a list of characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
import re
input_str = "(12+x1)*(y2-15)"
output = list(filter(lambda x: x.strip() not in [''], re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', input_str)))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['(', '12', '+', 'x1', ')', '*', '(', 'y2', '-', '15', ')']
```